# Katalon Studio error Unable to open browser with url: ''

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I'm new to Katalon Studio and I want to do some simple web-tests. So I try to open browser, but always getting error Unable to open browser with url: ''
It doesnt work with both chrome and firefox browsers. However when I try to run it in Web Recorder it works perfect with both browsers

I already tried to add

```
{“CHROME_DRIVER”:{“args”:["–no-sandbox","–disable-infobars"]}}
```

as it was mentioned in threads with the same error

If someone help, I would be glad

```
WebUI.openBrowser("")
// some code
WebUI.closeBrowser()
```

Full error:

```
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url: ''
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:56)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:60)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$openBrowser.call(Unknown Source)
    at new_case.run(new_case:16)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:336)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:327)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:306)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:298)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:232)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1556561167193.run(TempTestCase1556561167193.groovy:21)
Caused by: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: No driver is set for execution.
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory.startNewBrowser(DriverFactory.java:213)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory.openWebDriver(DriverFactory.java:188)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.doCall(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword$_openBrowser_closure1.call(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:20)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:56)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:60)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$openBrowser.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script1556556645291.run(Script1556556645291.groovy:16)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What Chromedriver version are you using?

Comment: 1) did you try WebUI.openBrowser('') WebUI.navigateToUrl(YOURURL) 2) in which profile you are running Katalon project(default or your customized one)?

Comment: I have the problem with firefox. It works if you set an url in openBrowser .... then I write `openBrowser(<google>)`  and then navigate to the good app url ... It's just a trick but it works

Answer (score 2):

Just update your chrome drive from tools->Update WebDrivers -> chrome

Comment: Thank you so so much. Two months later I and my team get this Chrome issues fixed -"user data directory is already in use"..... For the past two months we have been trying different ways like ChromeOptions class, chrome, placing drivers into C:// drive, UserData profile and so on. None of them worked. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

There is `No driver is set for execution.` in your error trace. Make sure you have the right version of [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). You should update the version to match your Chrome version. [How to update](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/update-or-replace-web-browser-drivers-and-selenium.html#how-to-replace).

Also, see that your [execution settings](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/execution-settings.html#default-execution-settings) are ok.

And finally, your error trace shows you are using DriverFactory class. You might need to add the path to Chromedriver at the top of your script:

```
System.setProperty(‘webdriver.chrome.driver’, ‘path to chromedriver’)
```

Comment: How to install previous versions of [Chromedriver](https://forum.katalon.com/t/how-to-download-install-previous-versions-of-chromedriver-exe/23993).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
Finally I found out katalon full path is not pure english chracter.
I move katalon to whole English path,then it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')
WebUI.navigateToUrl(YOURURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Download latest Chrome driver and replace old chrome driver with the new at below `kataon` location:

```
C:\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-6.3.2\configuration\resources\drivers\chromedriver_win32
```

Or

Directly update from Kataon APP. Refer Below Screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhWbP.png)